# ACL implementation in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there any generic way to implement ACL in ExtJS MVC application. As ExtJS is more for B2B , ACL is the key requirements for most of B2B system. Like Internationalisation is there any common approach to implement the ACL. 
If it Backend neutral it is fine, or if there is any good implementation structure which goes best with Spring-Security also it is well and good.

Comment: ExtJS controls entire frontend UI, so if we want to control certain button or panel for certain role there can be a generic approach with that framework itself which was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

An ACL is used to securely *control* access to information and grant privileges. Therefore, ACL logic needs to be run in an environment which users have no full access to: their access is being controlled, after all.

Now, Ext JS is a web *frontend* framework. Users *do* have full access to frontend at all times: they can see the JavaScript code (even though it may be obfuscated), tamper with it, forge AJAX requests etc. You simply could not rely on / trust ACL if it was implemented within the frontend. Therefore, there is no ACL in Ext JS (like in any other frontend framework).

> if we want to control certain button or panel for certain role there
>   can be a generic approach with that framework itself

Assigning roles and behaviour to buttons and panels is a very generic approach to building applications on its own — like the panels and buttons themselves. There cannot be any specificity in that approach in regards to  what purpose the panels and buttons are used for. Whilst you can use grid panels to show user lists and buttons to grant privileges to the users, the actual ACL will be implemented in the *backend*, and the panels and buttons will remain being just UI, not ACL.

P. S. Originally I did not intend to explain this so verbosely. I posted a short comment to the question summarizing the whole point in one sentence. But someone deleted the comment for some unknown reason. So here we are.